# Replace existing class definition at runtime with newly created type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, runtime, .net-4.6.1

**Demorepo**:

https://github.com/gabbersepp/csharp-dynamic-replace-class

**How to use**:

1. Checkout
2. Compile
3. Delete TestLib.dll & TestLib.pdb from console/bin/Debug
4. Execute console.exe through cmd

**Read first**:

I have something in mind I want to achieve at work and I think that this would be the best solution. So please do not discuss if I can solve this with another way. If I would like to discuss about this, I will create a new SO post.

**Given**:

A class in a lib:

```
namespace Test.TestLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

And a second class which creates an instance of it:

```
namespace console
{
    public class AnotherClass
    {
        public void Create()
        {
            new Class1();
        }
    }
}
```

And a console app that calls `create`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //...
        new AnotherClass().Create();
    }
```

Please keep in mind that only `Class1` is in an extra lib. The other two classes are in the same.

**What I want to do**:

Replace the Type `Class1` at runtime:

```
        AssemblyName dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName("TestLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        dynamicAssembly =
            AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var dynamicModule = dynamicAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("TestLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
        var modelType = dynamicModule.DefineType("Test.TestLib.Class1", TypeAttributes.Class).CreateType();
```

This works. If i am using the Activator: `Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);` I get a new instance of this type.

**But**:

When the line with `new Class1` is reached, an exception is thrown:

> Unbehandelte Ausnahme: System.MethodAccessException: Fehler beim
>   Versuch der Methode "console.AnotherClass.Create()", auf Methode
>   "Test.TestLib.Class1..ctor()" zuzugreifen.    bei
>   console.AnotherClass.Create()

**Something like**:

> Unhandled exception: System.MethodAccessException: An error occurred
>   while trying to access the method "console.AnotherClass.Create ()"
>   method "Test.TestLib.Class1..ctor ()".
>       at console.AnotherClass.Create ()

**Question**:

Is this possible?

**Sidenote**:
The deletion of the TestLib files from the /debug folder is required because otherwise the `AsemblyResolve` Event (please see the repo for a full example) is not raised

Comment: You may check `Pose` or `Prig` from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031984/any-alternative-to-shim-feature-provided-in-microsoft-fake-framework , for placing a shim substituting a specific type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add  `TypeAttributes.Public` to DefineType, it will execute successfully
Check this: https://github.com/aIjundi/csharp-dynamic-replace-class

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of your newly created Type is not public, hence the `MethodAccessAcception`.

You can create a public default constructor using the following call on the `TypeBuilder` instance:

```
var modelTypeBuilder = dynamicModule.DefineType("Test.TestLib.Class1", TypeAttributes.Class);
modelTypeBuilder.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);
var modelType = modelTypeBuilder.CreateType();
```

Otherwise you could use `modelTypeBuilder.DefineConstructor()` to set more possible options.

Comment: Hi, I only had to make the whole type public as mentioned by Sohaib. Thanks for your help.